# Local Cran Repo gives error with rsconnect deployApp

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy an application through R Shiny. When using the following command,

```
rsconnect::deployApp('path to app')
```

I encountered two errors:

1. Unable to determine package source for Bioconductor package impute
2. A [private package] was installed from sources; Packrat will assume this package is available from a CRAN-like repository during future restores

To resolve the first, I use the following command

```
options(repos = BiocInstaller::biocinstallRepos())
```

I have been struggling to resolve the second error of trying to add the path to the private package to my repository. Based on other posts, I tried

```
myCRAN <- path.expand("path to private package")
options(repos = c(oldRepos, myCRAN = myCRAN))
```

But this still results in the error: Warning: unable to access index for repository ... cannot download all files.

As this is the first app I am deploying, I would appreciate any help in resolving this error.

Comment: I had the same problem as you describe in number 1, and your suggested solution, calling `options(repos = BiocInstaller::biocinstallRepos())` worked - but I don't get why. Care to elaborate what actually happens?